# Convert daytime in string to datetime in sqllite 3?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, timestamp

I'm storing datetime value in SqlLite3 in TEXT column. data is stored as `2018 Nov 16 15:53:01`. How do I convert it back to datetime ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to convert a date string with `Nov`, even using `strftime`.  You should _always_ store your dates in SQLite using an ISO format which will sort properly.  So, you should have stored `2018-11-16 15:53:01`.

Comment: You could do it with `substr()` and a big `CASE` expression to turn the month name into a number, but, yeah, it's better to store your timestamp in one of the [formats understood by sqlite date & time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). This also has extra benefits like being able to sort them.

Comment: You could use a scripting language like Python to query the values, parse them as datetimes and write back to database. Syntax would be `dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming :-

1. that the table is named **convdt**, and
2. that you wish to change(UPDATE) all the rows in the table itself, and
3. that the table is not defined using the WITHOUT ROWID keywords

then I believe that the following will do that :-

```
WITH 
    cte1(rowid,dc1) AS (
    SELECT
        rowid,
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                            replace(
                                                replace(
                                                    replace(data,'Jan','01'),
                                                'Feb','02'),
                                            'Mar','03'),
                                        'Apr','04'),
                                    'May','05'),
                                'Jun','06'),
                            'Jul','07'),
                        'Aug','09'),
                    'Sep','09'),
                'Oct','10'),
            'Nov','11'),
        'Dec','12')
    FROM convdt
    ),
    cte2(rowid,dc2) AS ( SELECT rowid,substr(dc1,1,4)||'-'||substr(dc1,6,2)||'-'||substr(dc1,9) FROM cte1)
    UPDATE convdt SET data = (SELECT dc2 FROM cte2 WHERE cte2.rowid = rowid);
    SELECT * FROM convdt;
```

This uses two Common Table Expressions.

The first **cte1** extracts the **rowid** and the **data** columns replace Jan with 01, Feb with 02 and so on (naming the **data** column as **dc1**)

The second **cte2** then extracts the **rowid** and the **dc1** column from cte1 reformatting to adhere to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format.

All rows of the **convdt** table are then updated, obtaining the replacement value from cte2 according to the **rowid**.

### Working Example/Test Code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS convdt; -- For testing only drop the table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS convdt (data TEXT); -- For testing only create the table
INSERT INTO convdt VALUES  -- For testing only populate the table
    ('2018 Jan 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Feb 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Mar 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Apr 16 15:53:01'),
    ('2018 May 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Jun 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Jul 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Aug 16 15:53:01'),
    ('2018 Sep 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Oct 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Nov 16 15:53:01'),('2018 Dec 16 15:53:01')
;
SELECT * FROM convdt; -- Extract all the data for comparison before the updates
WITH 
    cte1(rowid,dc1) AS (
    SELECT
        rowid,
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                            replace(
                                                replace(
                                                    replace(data,'Jan','01'),
                                                'Feb','02'),
                                            'Mar','03'),
                                        'Apr','04'),
                                    'May','05'),
                                'Jun','06'),
                            'Jul','07'),
                        'Aug','09'),
                    'Sep','09'),
                'Oct','10'),
            'Nov','11'),
        'Dec','12')
    FROM convdt
    ),
    cte2(rowid,dc2) AS ( SELECT rowid,substr(dc1,1,4)||'-'||substr(dc1,6,2)||'-'||substr(dc1,9) FROM cte1)
    UPDATE convdt SET data = (SELECT dc2 FROM cte2 WHERE cte2.rowid = rowid);
    SELECT * FROM convdt; -- Extract all the data to show the result of the conversion
```

### Results

#### Before the table is updated :-

[image]

#### After the conversion :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will do the update, simply by changing the `MMM` month part with a double digit number.  
The last `CASE` statement checks if the day number is only 1 digit and if so it pads it left with 1 `0`.

```
UPDATE test SET datecol = 
    substr(datecol, 1, 4) || '-' ||  
    CASE substr(datecol, 6, 3)
        WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
        WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
        WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
        WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
        WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
        WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
        WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
        WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
        WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
        WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
        WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
        WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
        ELSE substr(datecol, 6, 3) 
    END || '-' ||
    CASE substr(datecol, 11, 1)
        WHEN ' ' THEN '0' || substr(datecol, 10)
        ELSE substr(datecol, 10)
    END
```